# Oracle Apex 5.x changing modal dialoge page size

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created a modal dialoge page in oracle apex 5. I want to change the size of the dialoge e.g height to 600px. Any idea how this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. In the App. Builder Select your page, then look for the Dialog properties Width, Height. Just enter the values, apply and reload the page.

Comment: Do you know why the height does not work with screen percentage? It works fine for the width, but not the hight.